# Mysql - Primary key listing in the wrong order

Tags: mysql, database, list

Usually do the query:

```
select * from table
```

It should be listed ordered by the primary key in ascending order, but it does not.
I think it's a problem in my primary key, but have used the commands to repair and it did not work.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and query that produces this behavior?

Comment: "Did not work" wins the award for the best problem explanation in 2016, it's so totally clear what went wrong and how, I just wonder why there aren't people bombarding you with solutions.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL makes absolutely no guarantee about what order the data comes to you unless you provide an `ORDER BY` statement.

For example...

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This is the only way to guarantee that your data comes back sorted by ID. Otherwise (depending on the engine you're using for the table), it could come back in any random order. Perhaps, for example, the data comes back in the order that rows were inserted, which *might not be apparent from the id values with respect to eachother*.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL  the  `order`  is not anpredefined or inherent property of a set of data.

Then, is not garanteeted that your data are returned  in a predefined  order .. this include  also the primary key  order 
If you want a proper order by you must use the `ORDER BY`  clause explicatally .